# pass data from tableview to another tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, segue

I am a beginner in swift and I really want to fix this problem. What I am trying is to pass data from tableview to another but when I run the code, it only show me a blank tableview. Here is my code in source tableviewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

class C1TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var categorisePagePOneName = ["CLOTHING", "SHOES", "ACCESSORIES", "THEME"]
var selectedIndex = Int()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return categorisePagePOneName.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdt = "Conecell"
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdt, for: indexPath) as! C1TableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = categorisePagePOneName[indexPath.row]


    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}


func laodForNextPage(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "connect2", sender: self)
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    if segue.identifier == "connect2" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! C2TableViewController
        vc.firstRow = categorisePagePOneName[self.selectedIndex]

    }
}
```

}

Then here is my code in another tableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class C2TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var firstRow: String!


var secondArray: [String] = []


var clothingCat = ["ALL CLOTHING", "THEME", "JACKET", "T-SHIRT", "SHIRT", "SWEATSHIRT", "HOODIES", "PANTS", "JEANS", "SHORTS", "KNITWEAR", "VESTS"]

var shoesCat = ["ALL SHOES", "THEME", "BOOTS", "SANDALS", "SNEAKERS"]

var asscessoriesCat = ["ALL ASSCESSORIES", "THEME", "HAT","BAGS", "JEWELLERY", "EYEWEAR", "WATCHES", "WALLETS", "SOCKS", "UNDERWEAR"]

var themeCat = ["VINTAGE", "KOREA","JAPAN", "SPORTY"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    }

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return secondArray.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "C2", for: indexPath) as! C2TableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    switch firstRow {
     case "CLOTHING":
         secondArray = clothingCat

     case "SHOES":
         secondArray = shoesCat

     case "ASSCESSORIES":
     secondArray = asscessoriesCat

     case "THEME":
         secondArray = themeCat

     default:
         break
     }
    cell.textLabel?.text = secondArray[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}
```

}

I am not sure if I am using switch in this case correctly

Comment: You have to implement `prepare(for segue` and put the code after the `performSegue` line in there. And pass the index path as `sender`

Comment: I try to implement like this prepare(for: segue, sender: self.selectedIndex), but it doesn't work.  T.T

Comment: Please clean up your code, ensure it is valid Swift (it is not), remove any comments, whitespace and code that do not help clarify your question such the `#warning` comments, empty `func`s, auto-generated comments etc.

Answer (score 1):

Replace (the custom method `laodForNextPage` is useless anyway)

```
func laodForNextPage(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "connect2", sender: self)
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    if segue.identifier == "connect2" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! C2TableViewController
        vc.firstRow = categorisePagePOneName[self.selectedIndex]

    }
}
```

with

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "connect2", sender: indexPath)
}
```

and implement

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "connect2" {
        let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
        let vc = segue.destination as! C2TableViewController
        vc.firstRow = categorisePagePOneName[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

And you can delete `selectedIndex`

Comment: Thanks! but there is still a signal SIGABRT in line let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath What can I do with that?

Comment: the error show that the indexPath is use of undeclared type 'Foundation'

Comment: If you pass the `indexPath` as `sender` in `performSegue` it cannot crash

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this function while the sender is the indexPath

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

}
```